# Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 Refractoring possible?

Tags: macos, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta4

I'm planning to upgrade my code to swift 2.0 and to use Xcode 7 in the near future. At the moment my app is still dependen on some frameworks that do not work with Swift2.0 yet.

Hast refractoring become possible with Xcode 7 or will it become possible?

At the moment (Xcode 6.4) it only works for Obj-C. If it is not planned for Xcode 7 I might as well do it in the current version by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From XCode 9, Swift refactoring is possible. Announced in WWDC 2017.

> **Refactoring**. Refactoring built right into the editing experience and works across Swift, Objective-C, Interface Builder, and many other file types.

For more refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html)

Answer (score 3):

As of beta 3 :
"Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code."

Comment: thx. Does anybody have news on when it will be possible. I mean it is a basic feature of any IDE